# ld: undefined reference to avformat_network_init@LIBAVFORMAT_53

Tags: ros, opencv, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I wrote a node that converts webcam images to ROS messages, I am using opencv but the linker yells:

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `avformat_new_stream@LIBAVFORMAT_53'
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `avformat_network_init@LIBAVFORMAT_53'
```

How do I overcome this problem?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34269/ld:-undefined-reference-to-avformat_network_init@libavformat_53/) by [sciarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1397/sciarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the problem by upgrading my stock libavformat to the latest one using Jon's PPA:
[https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg)

Basically av_new_stream() was renamed to avformat_new_stream().
ffmpeg is quite famous for frequently changing API names..which causes lots of overhead for developers.

---

Originally posted by [leeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/3031/leeq/) with karma: 26 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2